# Docker api running through host but not accesible with postman

Tags: docker, dockerfile, continuous-deployment

I do not understand why I have this problem

Edit: it is on w10

I tested my api running on the ide correctly, using mongodb installed locally, and using postman, and I did not have problems.

To run it on docker, I used mongo official image and I correctly connected from my host with mongo compass. I used:

```
docker run -v mongodata:/data/db -d -p 27017:27017 --name dockermongo mongo:latest
```

The problem is during using the api

I built the api docker image with

```
FROM openjdk:17
EXPOSE 8080
ADD "target/springbootskeletonapi-v1.0.0.jar" "springbootskeletonapi-v1.0.0.jar"
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/springbootskeletonapi-v1.0.0.jar"]
```

And run correcly with

```
docker run -d --network=host --name springbootskeletonapi  springbootskeletonapi:latest
```

It connected correctly to the mongo running on docker, but when I try the api using postman, it throws
`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080`

Also I noticed that when I do `docker container ps`, the colum port for mongo is correct `27017:27017` but the app is empty.

I do not know if it is a sign of the problem

Normally I used the -p port:port value, but in this case I used the same host

Answer (score 0):

The `EXPOSE` directive does nothing. You should use something like `-p8080:8080` to expose your container.
You could also see that the port is not opened (if using `Linux`) with `ss -tulpn` or `netstat -tulpn` and `grep` with `8080`.

```bash
ss -tulpn | gerp 8080
```

Comment: There's a thing, api on docker is using mongo on docker
So in order to connect the api to mongo (both on docker)
I should use --network, that causes a conflict with --port
If I use --port I will get (using docker run -d -p8080:8080 --name springbootskeletonapi  springbootskeletonapi:latest)
2023-03-20 15:56:06 2023-03-20T20:56:06.009Z  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
and it creates a new problem.

Comment: Do you want to both be accessible from the `host`?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I suggest using `compose` as it is more convenient in attaching service together and putting those in the same network.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will try that if the problem continue

Comment: I have noticed that the conflict is caused by
`spring.data.mongodb.port=27017`
`spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost`
`spring.data.mongodb.database=skeleton` it forces to use --network=host